# ignoring nextline in the grep command

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, command-prompt

I want to print "word" keyword with specific way.For example i have 3 different files named 1 2 3

1:

word x y

word

2:

x word y

3:

x y word

word

x

---

and output should be like that

for 1 : word x and just word

for 2 : x word

for 3 : y word and word

but in my code first and third output => word x and y word AND y word and word x

in brief how can i separate the line?

```
    #!/bin/bash
wordCount() {
    for i in "$1"/*; do
        if [ -d "$i" ]; then
            wordCount "./${i}" "$2"
        else
            if grep -q "$2" "$i"; then
                local format=($(grep "$2" "$i"))

                for ((x=0; x< ${#format[@]} ;x++))
                do
                  if [ "${format[$x]}" = "$2" ]
                  then
                    if [ \( "$x" -gt "0" \) ] && [ \( "$x" -lt "$((${#format[@]}-1))" \) ]
                    then
                      echo "${format[$x-1]}" "${format[$x]}" "${format[$x+1]}"
                    elif [ "$x" -eq "$((${#format[@]}-1))" ]
                    then
                      echo "${format[$(($x-1))]}" "${format[$(($x))]}"
                    else
                      echo "${format[$x]}" "${format[$(($x+1))]}"
                    fi
                  fi
                done

            fi
        fi
    done

}
```

Comment: `with specific way` in what way? Using which rules?

Comment: if "word" is at the beginning of the line print "word" and next word in the line, if "word" is at the end of the line print "word" and previous word in the line, if "word in the middle print prev "word" next @KamilCuk  i suppose grep is not the right option isn't it ?

Comment: No, grep only manipulates on a single line. If you search only for the current line and print something from the current line and the next line, this looks easy with sed, but to write it I would need more examples. Please post your input and ouptut examples inside code-blocks so they can be nicely formatted and reviewed